# How to install php7 for Nginx, Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, nginx

I have a request for the installation php7 for Apache

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv
```

What a complete request must be for Nginx?

Comment: this package is the most important `php7.0-fpm`

Comment: I think most delete libapache2-mod-php7.0 And request will this: sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv

Comment: Guys, please, give me correct full command.

Comment: run magento readiness check, it will show you whats missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace libapache2-mod-php7.0 with php7.0-fpm.

like

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 with php7.0-fpm php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv
```

Looks like better to add `php7.0-opcache php7.0-soap php7.0-json php7.0-xml` to list of modules

Comment: Right? sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv